# How can i pass array_column value to another array - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

i'm generating csv file for my attendance report, here's my query on selecting all the students and their logs:

```
    $students = User::has('userStudentAttendance')->with(['userStudentAttendance' => function($query) use ($details,$search_from, $search_to){
        $query->where('status', $details);
        $query->where(function($query) use ($search_from, $search_to){
            $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'), [$search_from, $search_to]);
        });
        $query->groupby('user_id')->groupby(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'));
    }])
    ->leftjoin('sys_user_student', 'sys_user_student.user_id', '=', 'sys_user.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_section', 'sys_mf_section.section_id', '=', 'sys_user_student.section_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_grade', 'sys_mf_grade.grade_id', '=', 'sys_mf_section.grade_id')     
    ->where('user_type_id', '4')
    ->where('sys_mf_section.section_id', $request->getParam('section_id'))
    ->where('sys_mf_grade.grade_id', $request->getParam('grade_id'))    
    ->orderBy('sys_user.last_name') 
    ->get();

    if ($students->count() > 0)
    {

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($test_array);
        exit();

        $csv = $this->csv;

        $csv->exportHeader('attendance (' . date_format(date_create($request->getParam('search_from')),"M-d-Y") . ' - ' . date_format(date_create($request->getParam('search_to')),"M-d-y") . ')');
        $csv->startInstance();

        $csv->addRow([                  
                'Student No.',
                'Fullname',
                'Gender',
                'Date & Time'
            ]);

        foreach ($students as $student) {

            $logs = $student->userStudentAttendance;
            $logs_array = array_column($logs, 'created_at');

            $csv->addRow([                  
                $student->identification_number,
                $student->last_name.", ".$student->first_name,
                $student->gender,
                $student->userStudentAttendance
            ]);
        }

        $csv->endInstance();

        die();
    }
```

the `$userStudentAttendance` is giving a `json` object, so to display this in `php` i used

`$logs = json_decode($userStudentAttendance)`

to convert it to an associative array, then i converted it to `array_column` to get the only column that i want to display

`$logs_array = array_column($logs, 'created_at')`

then i changed `$student->userStudentAttendance` inside the `$csv->addRow([])`

it looks like this now:

```
         foreach ($students as $student) {

            $csv->addRow([                  
                $student->identification_number,
                $student->last_name.", ".$student->first_name,
                $student->gender,
                $logs_array
            ]);
        }
```

then when convert it now to csv, the row of `$logs_array` is empty. What's wrong? can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: add 2nd argument true to get array ? `$logs = json_decode($userStudentAttendance, true)`

Comment: i've tried it, still the same :( , it gives me only a word "Array"

Comment: What is the value of `$logs_array`? Is there anything? Or it is null?

Comment: hi @u_mulder `$logs_array` had the value that i need, but when i put it to `$csv->addRow([])` it becomes null

Comment: If `$logs_array` is array, then I suppose `addRow` skips this array value, because it expects this value to be a __string__.

Comment: for array_column to work, you must pass array given like in this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). So before proceeding with array_column first check whether you are getting array like mentioned in documentation

Comment: so what can i do now? to convert it to string?

Comment: With `implode`.

Comment: i've already checked that documentation  @rahulsm

Comment: @u_mulder !!!!! you saved my life!!!! thanks a lot!! `implode` works very smooth!!! thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, `addRow` expects every item of argument array to be a string, so it can be put into csv file. Your call to `array_column` returns array, which is not a string. That's why you need to `implode` array values, for example:

```
$csv->addRow([                  
    $student->identification_number,
    $student->last_name.", ".$student->first_name,
    $student->gender,
    implode(',', $logs_array)    // Here we implode values
]);
```